# Wordpress custom post type ajax call empty

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpress custom post type which can be filtered using an AJAX call. It is match results for a kids football team and initially populates the page with the most current season. I re-use the AJAX PHP function to initially populate the page and this works fine.

When I choose another season, to show the results from that season, the correct season is passed and retrieved via $_GET['season'] but no results are returned. The season is an Advanced Custom Fields stored field.

These are my arguments for the WP_Query which works fine when not AJAX.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'results',
  'meta_key' => 'date',
  'meta_query'=> array(
    array(
      'key' => 'result_season',
      'value' => $show_season,
      'compare' => '='
    )
  ),
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'post_date' => 'DESC' )
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My AJAX call is this and it is passing the correct season.

```
$.ajax({
  url:jQuery(this).data('action'),          
  data:{ action: jQuery(this).data('filter'), season: jQuery(this).data('season') },
  beforeSend:function(xhr){
  },
  success:function(data){
    jQuery('#season-results').html(data); // insert data
  }
});
```

I have something similar working on another site for a simple job search. I MUST be doing something wrong, am I?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After almost 3 weeks of investigating this it came to me whilst running!

The site is Multisite and the CPT exists on all sites except the main site. get_current_blog_id() was returning 1 when called via AJAX and so no results were returned as none existed on site 1. I now pass the site ID into the AJAX call and retrieve using GET and hey presto it works now. The correct site ID is passed when the function isn't an AJAX call which is why it worked when called this way.

```
$.ajax({
        url:jQuery(this).data('action'),            
        data:{ action: jQuery(this).data('filter'), season: jQuery(this).data('season'), site: jQuery(this).data('site') },
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            //jQuery('#map-overlay').addClass('active');
        },
        success:function(data){
            jQuery('#season-results').html(data); // insert data
            //jQuery('#map-overlay').removeClass('active');
        }
    });


$current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

if ( isset($_GET['site']) ) {   
    $current_blog_id = $_GET['site'];
}
```